# Python3. Prompt requires ctrl+c and halts script

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm writing a small script that runs through a directory and attempts to obtain version numbers by running "filename --version". Now for the most part it works or fails in a manageable way. However I've come across one file "iptables-restore" in /sbin/ that fails when --version is passed to it. However the failure leaves the prompt in a state that requires a ctrl+z or ctrl+c to return to the prompt, and thus halts my script.

Here's the code:

```
try:            
        subOut = subprocess.check_output([fname, "--version"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpE:                                                                                                   
        fObj.write('{0:25}RETURN CODE:{1:15}\t\t{2:30}\n'.format(fnamecolon, cpE.returncode, cpE.output))
        fnamecolon = ''
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

I just wondered if there's an elegant way to handle this - either via a return code or perhaps an Exception.

I'm fairly new to Python and am doing this for practice really - so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks all!

Comment: pass `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` to `check_output`?

Comment: Maybe add very short timeout? In most cases, printing the version of a program is a near-instant operation, if something takes more than 0.1s then it's probably not going to end properly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So this works better - probably still some things I'm not understanding though...

```
try:
        # devnull=open(os.devnull, 'w')
        try:
            from subprocess import DEVNULL # Python 3
        except ImportError:
            DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)
        subOut = Popen([fname, "--version"], stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        output = subOut.stdout.read()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpE:                                                                                                   
        fObj.write('{0:25}RETURN CODE:{1:15}\t\t{2:30}\n'.format(fnamecolon, cpE.returncode, cpE.output))
        fname = ''
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        # fObj.write('{0:30}{1:30}{2:30}\n'.format(fname, e.returncode, e.output))
        pass
```

Comment: `CalledProcessError` never happens in this code. You probably want: `output = check_output([progname, '--version'], stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)` intstead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. I think that was in there from the last thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce it: `iptables-restore --version` commands waits for input without `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` [suggested by @mata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935940/python3-prompt-requires-ctrlc-and-halts-script#comment55632014_33935940):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

cp = subprocess.run(['iptables-restore', '--version'], 
                    stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(cp.returncode, cp.stdout, cp.stderr)
```